# Should Users Pay for Using iPhone Apps on Multiple Devices?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a senario that if the application if been purchased from my 1account for 1device(Lets say iphone 3) and if i installed same app to the other device with same itunes login details into the another device (iphone 4) should i have to pay again? or should i have to pay again for all my inapp purchase which is already been paid?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is unclear whether you are asking as a user or a developer. Assuming you are a user, as far as I know in-app purchases and apps should be installed for free if you use the same account. I know that some apps have a "restore purchases button". If you are a user, this question probably should be moved to http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is an iPhone 4Gs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't want to pay morer than once if your Product type is Non-consumable.

Check out **Registering Products with the App Store** concept in [In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html).

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: In-app purchases can be consumable. Apps are never treated as consumable.

Comment: Yes @duskwuff, I do know, In-App Purchase can be Consumable. that's why I have specified in my answer that "user doesn't need to purchase product again if product type for app is Non-Consumable"

Answer (score 0):

Apple's rules state the app belongs to the account, not the device.  You're not allowed to restrict access to apps (or non-consumable IAP) to a single device.

If you install the app on another device you should be able to restore any previously purchased (non-consumable) IAP to that new device.

Comment: While generally true, Apple does allow for separate iPad and iPhone/iPod touch apps. But once purchased for either class, the app will install for free on all other devices of the same class used with the same iTunes account.

Comment: yes,agreed with @rmaddy